# Windows Service starting Java not working since Java Upgrade to 8

Tags: java, windows, rest, continuous-integration, bamboo

We've updated our buildserver (Atlassian Bamboo) to Java 8 (JDK).
Since then our integrationtests are failing because our started product does not open any port.

We are building with maven and as part of the integrationtest we are starting our builded product. Our product is a Rest-Api based in an OSGI (equinox) and Jetty.

I tried a lot of things, but nothing helped me to get the product start properly in the maven build.

When I log in on my remote machine and start the product manually everything works fine.

Some more information:
Our buildserver runs as a windows service and our product is written in plain Java.

Comment: Sounds like the windows firewall has not Been told to allow Java 8 through.

Comment: When I start the app manually everything works. Do you still think it could be the firewall? We are using Bitdefender and I already tried once with disabling it.

Comment: “our started product does not open any port.” How do you know this?  If an exception is occurring, please include the stack trace in your question.

Comment: I see the tests failing because of "connection refused" and on our remote machine I can see every open Port with 'netstat -an'

Comment: Are you using Bamboo Server or Bamboo Cloud. And are you using [local, remote or elastic agents](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/agents-and-capabilities-289277114.html)?

Comment: We are using Bamboo Server standalone on a remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you are affected by one or more of the issues discussed in [Custom AMIs will not start anymore in Bamboo Cloud (BAM-16291)](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-16291), notably that Bamboo is not compatible with [JDK8u60](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-16291?focusedCommentId=783480&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-783480) yet:

> Joda-time, one of the libraries used by Bamboo is not compatible with
>   8u60. We've fixed this problem, but the fix has not been rolled out
>   yet. Known breakages include S3 interaction and CodeDeploy plugin.

Most/All participants got things working again by downgrading to JDK8u45, as also recommended in [Atlassian's most recent update](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-16291?focusedCommentId=784295&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-784295):

> - Use JDK 8u45. The latest JDKs are incompatible with some 3rd party    libraries we're using.
> - Try to match the layout and scripts of our stock images as closely as possible. This will make it easier for us to provide help    if
>     anything goes wrong.
> - Choose Oracle if you have the choice between Oracle and OpenJDK flavor of JDK.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but it doesn't worked. I downgraded to 8u45 and set all parameters. ... I was full of hope after your post. But what is a Custom AMI ?

Comment: Sorry to hear - a [custom elastic image](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/creating-a-custom-elastic-image-289277146.html) is _an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) that is stored in one of Amazon data centres for use with the [Elastic Bamboo feature](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/about-elastic-bamboo-289277118.html)_. I should have clarified your Bamboo configuration upfront in order to judge whether this actually applies (just seemed to good of a match ...), have done so on your question now.

Comment: Was worth a try. Thanks